# when i fetch the data from database it give error on sql command . how can i fixed the code

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT (SUM(MAX(identifier)+1) FROM student_ids WHERE state ='state' AND  year='year');

SELECT (SUM(MAX(identifier)+1) FROM student_ids WHERE state ='state' AND  year='year')
LIMIT 0, 25
```

MySQL said: Documentation 
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM student_ids WHERE state ='state' AND  year='year')
 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1 
how can i fix the error

Comment: The error you see results from the `(` before the `SUM` and its matching `)` at the end of the query. The content of those two braces is `SUM(MAX(identifier)+1) FROM student_ids WHERE state ='state' AND  year='year'` and this does not make sense. So beginning with `FROM` the syntax is not valid any more. If you write `SELECT SUM(MAX(identifier)+1) FROM student_ids WHERE state ='state' AND  year='year';` then the syntax is correct, but the `SUM` is not correctly used.

Comment: let's use ` for \`year\`, \`state\`, ... because some are reserved. By chance year works maybe, but date as column name for example could return an error.

Answer (score 1):

The `SUM` function is for taking aggregates of columns, across multiple rows.  You don't need to use it to add a scalar value:

```
SELECT MAX(identifier) + 1 AS max_id
FROM student_ids
WHERE state = 'state' AND year = 'year';
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionnaly to @tim-biegeleisen, use ` for column names and table names, like this : `year`, `state`, ...

Because some words you uses are reserved. YEAR is reserved word and could return an error if you uses it as column name. SQL thinks you are calling the *year* function instead of a column named *year*.

```
SELECT MAX(`identifier`) + 1 AS `max_id`
FROM  `student_ids`
WHERE `state` = 'state' 
AND   `year`  = 'year' ;
```

Here is documentation about reserved words in mySQL :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html